# Android Location: ProximityAlert

Tags: android, geolocation

for my app, I need something like a proximity alert, which is registered to `LocationManager` by calling:

```
public void addProximityAlert (double latitude, double longitude, float radius, long, expiration, PendingIntent intent);
```

This default alert does fire only every 4 minutes if the screen is turned off. For my app, it is necessary to request location updates only via `NetworkProvider` and about every minute.

Is it possible to custimize the default settings, or do I have to create my own alert by requesting updates like I want it to?

Thanks in advance,
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the addProximityAlert uses both the providers internally (network as well as gps) and you cannot specify these, I don't see a way to configure this method.
The requestLocation updates can be used with network only provider and then you can use the [Haversine formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to calculate the distance difference.

The requestLocation updates states that values under 60000ms are not recommended though !

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is, now I know, that I have to create my own alert. The distance between to Locations can be calculated more easily by using: Location.distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)